# Display JSON as List in ViewController (Not in TableView)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsjsonserialization

I am producing a JSON string that I need to parse out and display onto the page. My JSON string outputs information about the contents of a CD like this:

```
[{"song_name":"Song 1","artist":"John","price":"$1"}, 
{"song_name":"Song 2","artist":"Anna","price":"$2"}, 
{"song_name":"Song 3","artist":"Ryan","price":"$3"}]
```

I would like to display the contents in my viewController in a list format displaying the song_name, artist, and price. I do not want to use a tableView to display this information, but would rather just have a list displayed. How might I go about doing this? I would assume that I need to use NSJSONSerialization, but have only used that for a tableView in the past. Thank you!

Comment: [what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: You can do it by using scrollview. Add UILabels with text on scrollview one below another seqeuntially. And set contentsize of scrollview such that all labels will be visible by scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to other answers, you can use only one label, just create NSMutableString (for dynamicly adding tracks info) with @"\n" between tracks info, pass it to label.text and set UILabel's property numberOfLines to 0

Comment: Very creative way of doing this!!

Comment: Is there a good way to format the text (i.e. the prices bold and the names italicized) or would that be too difficult using a single label?

Comment: In iOS 6.0 you can use attributedText, but UILabel hasn't this property in older version. You can try use UIWebView with its method - (void)loadHTMLString:(NSString *)string baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL instead UILabel to display formatted text in this versions

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

1. Parse the JSON and store the key-value pair(NSDictionary of CDs) in an NSArray (say infoArray)
2. Add a UIScrollview as a subview on your viewController's view.
3. Allocate UILabels dynamically, depending on infoArray count. Looking at your data I believe you can initialize labels with static frames i.e your y can remain static.
4. Add the text from the infoArray on this label.

Still, I would suggest use UITableView only. It is much simpler and a better approach

Answer (score 0):

You make an array of dictionaries using NSJSONSerialization indeed, then you parse this array one by one and create a view of every dictionary. You're probably best of using a method for this:

```
-(UIView *) listView: (NSString *)songName andArtist:(NSString *)artist andPrice:(NSString *)price andIndex:(int)viewIndex {
    //create your view here and do anything you want

    UIView *subView = [[UIView alloc] init] autoRelease];
    subView.frame = CGRectMake(0, viewIndex * 70, self.view.frame.width, 70);

    //add labels and other stuff


   // return the view
   return subView;
}
```

The you add it to the current view by setting different Y values so they appear underneath each other by using the viewIndex of the former method... So if you have an array it goes something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++) {

    NSDictionary *dict = [array objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *songName = [dict valueForKey:@"song_name"];
    NSString *artist = [dict valueForKey:@"artist"];
    NSString *price = [dict valueForKey:@"price"];

    UIView *tempView = [self listView:songName andArtist:artist andPrice:price andIndex:i];

    [self.view addSubView:tempView];

}
```

You have to add it all to a scrollview otherwise you will run into the problem of to many rows on the page. Google for UIScrollView if you don't know how.

But I would recommend against this approach.. Tableviews are there with a reason. They are made for this stuff. Because the also provide for scrolling, drawing and refreshing. If you can, use them!